# Cant Connect to Neura

Tags: android, ios, neura

I am having issues with the basic setup. I have gone through the iOS Quickstart guide, but when I click on the login button, I receive an error "ERROR_NOT_AUTHORIZED_APP_SIGNATURE"
what could I possibly be doing wrong?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Lets go through some basic steps:

1. Make sure that you are using the current version of the Neura SDK, visit the [devsite](https://dev.theneura.com) for more details.
2. This error is likely to occur because you haven't registered your application correctly with Neura, go to the Neura Devsite/MyApps, click on your application

   - If you are using Android, make sure the "Application Package Name" is similar to what you have entered in your android application.
   - If you are using iOS, make sure your "Bundle ID" is similar to the bundle id in your iOS app